# useCart - Get product modifiers added to the products - storefront-data-hooks - BigCommerce

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, bigcommerce

I am using BigCommerce's [storefront-data-hooks](https://github.com/bigcommerce/storefront-data-hooks#usecart) for creating the Cart functionality in my NextJS app. The issue I am facing is, how to get the product modifiers added to the product in Cart.

For [adding an item](https://github.com/bigcommerce/storefront-data-hooks#useadditem) to cart, I am doing it like this:

```
    await addItem({
        quantity: quantity,
        productId: product_id,
        optionSelections: selected_modifiers
       
    })
```

In the CART page, I am trying to display the details about the modifiers added for each PRODUCT. I am having hard time figuring it out as the documentation does not include these.

I tried searching in Google as well as checking the documentation of this storefront-data-hooks in GitHub

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.